# Berglund-Hübsch-Hori-Vafa mirror symmetry is a ring isomorphism?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mirror-symmetry, orbifolds

Let $W = \sum_{i=1}^{m} a_i \prod_{j=1}^{n} x_j^{b_{ij}}$ be a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$ in $n$ variables. I focus on the $m=n$ case (*invertible polynomial* in the Berglund-Hübsch terminology). Denote by $M_W$ the matrix of exponent of $W$ and consider $W^{T}$ the homogeneous polynomial associated to the transpose $M_W^{T}$.
Denote by $\mathrm{SL}(W)$ the subgroup of diagonal matrices with determinant $1$ such that $g.W = W$ for all $g \in \mathrm{SL}(W)$ (similarly defined $\mathrm{SL}(W^{T})$).

Let $J$ be the subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}(W)$ generated by $e^{2i \pi/d}.I_n$ and let $G \subset \mathrm{SL}(W)$ be a finite subgroup. There is a canonical way to define a dual group $G^{T} \subset \mathrm{SL}(W^{T})$, which I won't do here, but which is well-known.

I have been recently reading a survey by Clader and Ruan ([here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.1268.pdf)) on Mirror Symmetry, and they claim that under some non-degeneracy hypothesis on $W$, the B-model/A-model side of Mirror Symmetry in this situation can be formulated as an isomorphism:

$$\left(\bigoplus_{g} \mathrm{Jac}(W|_{\mathrm{Fix}(g)}) \right)^{G} \simeq H^{\bullet}_{CR}([X^{T}/\widetilde{G^{T}}]),$$

where $g$ runs through the various conjugacy classes of elements in $G$ on the left-handside and the term on the right is the orbifold (Chen-Ruan) cohomology of the orbifold $[X^{T}/\widetilde{G^{T}}]$, where $\widetilde{G^{T}} = G^{T}/J$ and $X^{T}$ is the variety defined by $W^{T}$ in $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$. I think I have two questions:

_Is this isomorphism expected to be an algebra isomorphism or just a graded vector space isormorphism?

_Is this (algebra?) isomorphism known to hold in the situation above-described? I know that Krawitz proved a similar statement where the orbifold-cohomology is replaced by the "orbifold" FRJW ring (relative cohomology of $\mathbb{C}^n$ with respect to Lefschetz thimbles associated to $W^{T}$), but I am more interested in a statement which would involve the orbifold cohomology of the orbifold $[X^{T}/\widetilde{G^{T}}]$.